# Python importing everything from module subdirectory

Tags: python, import, subdirectory

I'm trying to import all files from a sub-directory, so I figured I could write `__init__.py` in that sub-directory to import the files. However, when I do this it does not seem to import anything.

File structure:

```
prog.py
module/
    __init__.py
    code.py
```

Code for `prog.py`: `pass`

Code for `__init__.py`: `import code`

Code for `code.py`: `print('hello')`

When I run prog.py nothing happens. Why does it not print `hello`, and is there a better way to easily import everything from a sub-directory?

Comment: Your file structure does not show any directories...

Comment: Thanks, it was an oversight. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in `prog.py`:

```
import module
```

Python will only load packages or modules that are imported.

To make it work, you probably need jcollado's answer as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the following structure:

```
package
  __init__.py
  module.py
```

In `__init__.py` you can either try this:

```
import package.module
```

or this:

```
from . import module
```

This way, if `package` is in your `PYTHONPATH`, you'll get the expected behaviour:

```
>>> import package
hello
```

Comment: I realize this but it didn't answer either of my questions.

Comment: Reading again your question, I see that `prog.py` only contains `pass` (no `import` statement) and that you're just running `prog.py`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. From what I understand `__init__.py` should run regardless, and then import `code.py` from the sub-directory and thus be accessible by prog.

Comment: @Whef You have to explicitly import the package (even it it's called `module`, please note that it's package) to execute the code in `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a file structure like this:

```
prog.py
module/
    __init__.py
    code.py
```

Then `import module` would import the code in `module/__init__.py`and `import module.code` or `from module import code` would import the code in `module/code.py` under the local name "module.code" or "code".

Comment: I realize this but it didn't answer either of my questions.