# Python cannot import module from subdirectory even with a file named __init.py__ in the directory

Tags: python, import, package

I know this question has been asked many times here and I'v probably read most of the answers (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951980/python-importing-subdirectories) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551285/cant-import-python-module-from-a-subdirectory-with-a-simple-import-statement)) as well as the python documentation but still can not find an answer to my very simple import problem. It's so simple that I must miss something stupid but I don't see it yet.
I have setup the following structure:

```
myproject
    myscript.py
    MyPackage
        __init.py__
        mymodule.py
```

I just want to load `mymodule.p`y from `myscript.py` (or the commandline python interpreter which should be the same).

`myscript.py` contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MyPackage
```

`__init.py__` contains:

```
from . import mymodule
```

`mymodule.py` contains

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def myfunction():
    print "mymessage"
```

My goal is to call `myfunction` from `myscript.py` but if I try to call the module I get

```
$python myscript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "myscript.py", line 2, in <module>
   import MyPackage
ImportError: No module named MyPackage
```

## What I already tried:

- I tried everything under OSX and Ubuntu Linux to reduce the possibility of a faulty python installation.
- I set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to the `myproject` directory as well as to `.` and to both.
- I left `__init.py__` blank
- I tried the import statements also from the python interpreter started from the `myproject` directory
- I tried the following import statements:

  ```
  from MyPackage import mymodule
  import MyPackage.mymodule
  import MyPackage.mymodule as module
  ```

  all without success (same error message).

If I put `mymodule.py` in the project directory without using a package, import works fine. But I don't see why the import from the subpackages is not working.
Any idea how I can get that to work?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You need to verify if the `myproject` directory is listed in `sys.path`. Before importing `MyPackage`, does `sys.path` contain the right directory?

Comment: If I start the interpreter and execute `import sys` and `print sys.path` it shows a list containint the path of the "myproject" directory correctly: `['', '/Users/michael/Entwicklung/python/myproject', ... ]`

Comment: Right, so the package should be importable. There could be a *different* import error *in the package*. You said you already tried an empty `__init__.py`. Could you try that again, but make sure you remove all `*.pyc` files. Perhaps add a single `print "imported"` line in `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While editing the formatting of your post, I noticed you're calling your file `__init.py_`. That causes python to not recognize your `MyPackage` directory as a package, hence the `ImportError: No module named MyPackage`.

It should instead be **`__init__.py`** (Name **`__init__`**, extension **`.py`**). Then it will work, your project structure and import statements are otherwise correct.

One minor point though: You should also use `lower_underscore` style for naming your package. Packages are modules as well in Python, and they should follow the same naming conventions. See [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for details on recommended style and naming conventions. This is just a *convention* though, it has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Python is case sensitive so the package structure and imports will not match even under Windows.

Comment: Sure it is, and they match perfectly in his description: He calls the package `MyPackage` and imports it as `import MyPackage`, and the module `mymodule.py` and imports or references it as `from .. import mymodule`. Your syncing up the casing between module and package is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Wow, I'm really impressed that I spent three or more hours struggling with this problem and though reading the documentation again and again I completely overlooked the wrong naming of `__init__.py` that you spotted out. Perfect! Now it finally works, so thanks for your answer!